# Stuck when uninstalling visual studio 2013 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2013, uninstallation

I'm facing a problem.

I installed VS 2013 Ultimate RTM from Dreamspark long time ago, then recently installed the Update 3. The problem is that the update become corrupted, some features don't work correctly, repair doesn't help. I tried to uninstall VS but could not, every time I try to uninstall it, it's just stuck at "Workflow Manager ....". I even waited for a day, and the process still didn't continue.

Then I decided to overwrite the RTM installation with "Ultimate with update 4" downloaded from MS website, then tried uninstall it. This time it's hang at "Configuring your system ..."

It's so annoying, is there anyway to completely wipe out VS?

Comment: Frankly I doubt it, I have had similar issues. Perhaps system restore could help, but you would have to go way back and you could get new problems with missing windows updates.

Comment: looks like im out of luck. I allocated very little space for system restore, hence I dont have a restore point before the incident. :(

Comment: You could try a manual cleanup of the registry and to uninstall all MSSQL stuff and other VS components, but it is a very complicated install and it is hard to debug. If you have access to virtual machines it is a good idea to install a spare install there so you have Visual Studio available for situations such as what you experience. A virtual can generally always be restored to the last stored state.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling my Windows. Thanks for the help

Comment: I figured you'd have to. This is a bigger problem now with Visual Studio than it used to be. I suppose the general advice is to try to use virtuals for test versions of visual studio, and do as little as possible to your main box.

Comment: This SO post has numerous ways you can force an uninstall of VS 2013, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39663653/743